# storing non indexed binary data in lucene

Tags: lucene

How do you store non indexed array of bytes into lucene document?

I have tried these:

```java
     doc.add(new Field("bin1", new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte [100000]))));
     doc.add(new BinaryDocValuesField("bin2", new BytesRef(new byte [100000])));
```

and nothing worked (field not stored, unable to retrieve when querying)

test code:

```java
  String index="dms1";

  Directory indexDirectory = FSDirectory.open(Paths.get(index));
  StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
     IndexWriterConfig iwc = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
     iwc.setOpenMode(IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode
             .CREATE
     );
     //create the indexer
  IndexWriter iw = new IndexWriter(indexDirectory, iwc);

  {
     Document doc = new Document();

     doc.add(new TextField("id", "1", Field.Store.YES));
     doc.add(new Field("bin1", new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte [100000]))));
     doc.add(new BinaryDocValuesField("bin2", new BytesRef(new byte [100000])));

     iw.addDocument(doc);
     iw.commit();
  }

  DirectoryReader ir = DirectoryReader.open(indexDirectory);

  IndexSearcher is = new IndexSearcher(ir);


  QueryParser qp = new QueryParser(
          "",
          analyzer);
  Query q = qp.parse(
          //"content1:hp"
          "*:*"
  );
  TopDocs hits = is.search(q, 10);

  for (ScoreDoc scoreDoc : hits.scoreDocs) {
     Document doc = is.doc(scoreDoc.doc);

     System.out.println(doc);

     System.out.println("doc.getBinaryValue(bin1):" + doc.getBinaryValue("bin1"));;
     System.out.println("doc.getBinaryValues(bin1):" + doc.getBinaryValues("bin1"));;
     System.out.println("doc.getBinaryValues(bin1).length:" + doc.getBinaryValues("bin1").length);;
     System.out.println("doc.get(bin1):" + doc.get("bin1"));;

     System.out.println("doc.getBinaryValue(bin2):" + doc.getBinaryValue("bin2"));;
     System.out.println("doc.getBinaryValues(bin2):" + doc.getBinaryValues("bin2"));;
     System.out.println("doc.getBinaryValues(bin2).length:" + doc.getBinaryValues("bin2").length);;
     System.out.println("doc.get(bin2):" + doc.get("bin2"));;
  }
```

output:

```java
    Document<stored,indexed,tokenized<id:1>>
    doc.getBinaryValue(bin1):null
    doc.getBinaryValues(bin1):[Lorg.apache.lucene.util.BytesRef;@899e53
    doc.getBinaryValues(bin1).length:0
    doc.get(bin1):null
    doc.getBinaryValue(bin2):null
    doc.getBinaryValues(bin2):[Lorg.apache.lucene.util.BytesRef;@f98160
    doc.getBinaryValues(bin2).length:0
    doc.get(bin2):null
```

Could anyone shed a light on how to store the bytes and how to retrieve the values again?

I know other solution using base64 or other encoding to convert the bytes to text or storing it as file links, but what I need to know is a more efficient way to do this, since lucene API has "binary" methods so I thought that should be the correct way to do it.

lucene version: 5.3.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [`StoredField`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_1/core/org/apache/lucene/document/StoredField.html#StoredField(java.lang.String,%20byte[])).  You can pass in either the `BytesRef`, or the byte array itself into the field:

```java
byte[] myByteArray = new byte[100000];
document.add(new StoredField("bin1", myByteArray));
```

As far as retrieving the value, you are on about the right track there already.  Something like:

```java
Document resultDoc = searcher.doc(docno);
BytesRef bin1ref = resultDoc.getBinaryValue("bin1");
bytes[] bin1bytes = bin1ref.bytes;
```

---

By the way, the problem with the two fields you've tried:

- bin1:  When you pass a reader into the `Field` constructor, it decides to treat it as a `TextField` which will be indexed and not stored, effectively the opposite of what you are looking for.  That constructor is deprecated anyway, in favor of just using `TextField`

  If you had opted in favor just passing in the `byte[]` instead of the `Reader`, it actually would have worked, since that would have acted as a `StoredField` (as shown above), though that constructor is also deprecated).
- bin2:  DocValuesFields work differently.  You can [read up a bit on that here](http://blog.trifork.com/2011/10/27/introducing-lucene-index-doc-values/), if you are curious.