# Is it possible to make search engine with Lucene only using database column of which datatype is BLOB(byte array)?

Tags: java, database, logging, lucene, full-text-search

Is it possible to develop searching function with Lucene **without storing data as a file?**

I mean, I want to know the way how to make getting data which is byte array(=text file, BLOB) from RDB(PostgreSQL 12) and make searching function with Lucene.

It is okay that index files stored as a file but I hope there are some ways to not that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to have actual files to be able to index data with Lucene. If you add a TextField to a Lucene document you can use the constructor that takes a Reader and pass the text data through it.

https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/TextField.html

Comment: thanks for your opinion but i figured it out with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34324239/storing-non-indexed-binary-data-in-lucene)

I think I tried explain what my problem is but it doesn't deliver to you well but thanks for your opinion which is really helpful.

I figured it out the way with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34324239/storing-non-indexed-binary-data-in-lucene)